# $(this).serialize() -- How to add a value?

Tags: serialization, jquery

currently I have the following:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: this.action,
    data: $(this).serialize(),
});
```

This works fine, however I would like to add a value to data, so I tried

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: this.action,
    data: $(this).serialize() + '&=NonFormValue' + NonFormValue,
});
```

But that didn't post correctly. Any ideas on how you can add an item to the serialize string? This is a global page variable that isn't form specific.

Comment: Can you clarify what "that didn't post correctly" means? What happened? What was received by the server?

Comment: Shouldn't that be `'&NonFormValue=' + NonFormValue`?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

⛔ Instead of

```
 data: $(this).serialize() + '&=NonFormValue' + NonFormValue,
```

✅ you probably want

```
 data: $(this).serialize() + '&NonFormValue=' + NonFormValue,
```

You should be careful to URL-encode the value of `NonFormValue` if it might contain any special characters.

Comment: use `encodeURIComponent` to ensure that the `NonFormValue` does not have any special characters

Comment: I updated the answer by adding wrong and correct emojies. That was second time that I use this answer but I copy the wrong one.

Answer (score 242):

While matt b's answer will work, you can also use `.serializeArray()` to get an array from the form data, modify it, and use `jQuery.param()` to convert it to a url-encoded form. This way, jQuery handles the serialisation of your extra data for you.

```
var data = $(this).serializeArray(); // convert form to array
data.push({name: "NonFormValue", value: NonFormValue});
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: this.action,
    data: $.param(data),
});
```

Comment: This is definitely the best option - leaving the serialization entirely to jQuery, while still having the ability to add new values to those retrieved from the form.

Comment: This is the best way to do it, no playing with strings

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Clean and the right way

Comment: Can you help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73194619/how-can-i-add-formdata-with-html-beginform

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget you can always do:

```
<input type="hidden" name="NonFormName" value="NonFormValue" />
```

in your actual form, which may be better for your code depending on the case.

Answer (score 7):

firstly shouldn't

```
data: $(this).serialize() + '&=NonFormValue' + NonFormValue,
```

be

```
data: $(this).serialize() + '&NonFormValue=' + NonFormValue,
```

and secondly you can use

```
url: this.action + '?NonFormValue=' + NonFormValue,
```

or if the action already contains any parameters

```
url: this.action + '&NonFormValue=' + NonFormValue,
```

Comment: Your second answer wouldn't have the same effect as what the question asked for; `NonFormValue` would be sent as a URL parameter, not in the POSTed data. This might not be ideal if a) whatever's running on the server side expects it to be POSTed (eg using `request.POST` instead of `request.REQUEST` in Django), or b) `NonFormValue` is something that shouldn't appear in the URL bar or history either for security reasons or because it's a transient value.

Answer (score 6):

Add the item first and then serialize:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: this.action,
    data: $.extend($(this), {'NonFormValue': NonFormValue}).serialize()
});
```

Comment: Did not work for me as well. Though it extends the object but did not work as expected.

Answer (score 6):

We can do like:

```
data = $form.serialize() + "&foo=bar";
```

For example:

```
var userData = localStorage.getItem("userFormSerializeData");
var userId = localStorage.getItem("userId");

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: postUrl,
    data: $(form).serialize() + "&" + userData + "&userId=" + userId,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (response) {
        //do something
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

this better:

```
data: [$(this).serialize(),$.param({NonFormValue: NonFormValue})].join('&')
```

Comment: Please add a more detailed description as to why this is a better approach.

Comment: one line code and you can use json object for more params.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an extra function to process form data and you should add your nonform data as the data valu in the form.seethe example :

```
<form method="POST" id="add-form">
    <div class="form-group required ">
        <label for="key">Enter key</label>
        <input type="text" name="key" id="key"  data-nonformdata="hai"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required ">
        <label for="name">Ente Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name"  data-nonformdata="hello"/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="add-formdata-btn" value="submit">
</form>
```

Then add this jquery for form processing

```
<script>
$(document).onready(function(){
    $('#add-form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var formData = $("form").serializeArray();
        formData = processFormData(formData);
        // write further code here---->
    });
});
processFormData(formData)
{
    var data = formData;
    data.forEach(function(object){
        $('#add-form input').each(function(){
            if(this.name == object.name){
                var nonformData = $(this).data("nonformdata");
                formData.push({name:this.name,value:nonformData});
            }
        });
    });
    return formData;
}
```