# Why can't I append to my JSON object? (jQuery/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using the following code in an attempt to add a new attribute to bar object:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form').on("submit",preventDefault);
});

function preventDefault(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $url="contact/send";
    bar = $('form').serialize();
    bar["foo"]='xyz';
    //bar.foo="123";
    console.log(bar);
}
```

However I don't ever seem to get the value of bar.foo. If I look at the console in Chrome I always get a result similar to this:

```
name=Grahame&email=foo%40bar.com&message=Hello.
```

Why am I not getting the value/property of foo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use this:

```
bar = $('form').serialize();
bar += '&foo=xyz';
console.log(bar);
```

Currently you're trying to use `bar` as an array (or an object in your commented code). [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) actually generates a URL-ecoded string so you can simply append your value to it.

Answer (score 1):

Other answers here talk about how one might get around this, but no one is explaining *why* this is happening, so I figured I'll give it a shot.

#### Here is what is happening in the background:

- You call `.serialize` which produces a string
- Strings in JavaScript are primitive value types, so when you add a property to it, it "autoboxes" becomes a `String` *reference type object* for that call.
- You assign the property to it, which is added to the boxed object
- `console.log(bar);` logs the bar object, which is already again a string which is a primitive value type. Both because toString of the String type, and because of the `bar` being a primitive value type, you get the same initial value.

You can read more about this in [the secret life of primitives in JavaScript.](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/09/27/the-secret-life-of-javascript-primitives/) Or in [the specification](http://es5.github.com)

#### How to fix it

See [How to add a value to jQuery serialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539502/this-serialize-how-to-add-a-value) . That has already been answered there.

Answer (score 0):

`bar` is **serialized** form data. It is a *string* not an object.

If you want to add data do it you need to serialize that data:

```
bar += "&" + encodeURIComponent('foo') + "=" + encodeURIComponent('xyz');
```

(You can skip the encode URI components if you **know** that the data has no URL special characters in it).

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
bar = $('form').serializeArray();
bar["foo"]='xyz';
```