# What is the best way to add extra data to a jquery ajax post (in addition to a serialized form)?

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, post

I have the following code:

```
 $.post('/Calendar/Add', $("#calendarForm").serialize(), function (data) {

 });
```

and i want to add another piece of data in addition to all of the items in the #calendarForm.

so lets say i want to append an additional key value pair to the querystring:

```
  personId=223
```

I would rather not add extra hidden inputs into the calendarForm as that is what i am doing now and its kind of messy.  Is there any easy way to add an additional piece of data besides all of the value in the calendarForm when i call this post ?

I tried something like this:

```
 $.post('/Calendar/Add', $("#calendarForm").serialize() + "&personId=223", function (data) {

 });
```

but that didn't seem to work?

Comment: check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539502/this-serialize-how-to-add-a-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `serializeArray`

```
var data = $('#myFormName').serializeArray();
data.push({name: 'myParamName', value: 'MyParamValue'});
```

**Update1:**

You can use following code in `$.post`:

```
$.post('/Calendar/Add', data, function (data)    
{});
```

For more information have look at [this](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

Comment: and just pass in "data" instead of "$("#calendarForm").serialize() + "&personId=223"" ??

Comment: @leora Yeah that's the recommended idea. because `.serialize()` will return a string. Go ahead.

Comment: don't i need to convert the data array into a string first?

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like bellow

```
$.post('/Calendar/Add', { personId: 223,calendarForm: $("#calendarForm").serialize() },
         function (data) { });
```