# Adding Multiple Datas - Ajax PHP

Tags: php, ajax, forms

So I have this as my current data:

```
data: $(this).serialize()
```

How can I have that and add another one?

Like

```
data: {
    $(this).serialize(),
    test: 'hello'
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [$(this).serialize() -- How to add a value?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539502/this-serialize-how-to-add-a-value)

Comment: Please search SO before asking, ie. answer from question above http://stackoverflow.com/a/6539539/689579 - `data: $(this).serialize() + '&test=hello',`

Comment: Sean's link helped me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

More like this:

```
var serialized = $(this).serialize();

$.ajax({
    //...
    data: {
        serialized: serialized,
        text: 'hello'
    }
```

Comment: It didn't work. I have a bunch of things I need to pass. For example $_POST['email'] doesn't work now or anything other than 'text.'

Comment: You do need to specify the `type` as POST if you want to collect data in the post. `$.ajax()` defaults to `$_GET` as of jQuery ~1.8.

Comment: Also, did you get `serialized` from the ajax call?