# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at buildParams

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, ajaxform

I can't find where is mistake. please help

When I submit form I get below error in console

```
 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded     at buildParams
```

I saw different answers  but they didn't help me to find error

**Jquery**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var frm = $('#message-form');
    frm.on('submit',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: frm.attr("method"),
                url: "message/message_form/",
                dataType: 'json', 
                data: { csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}", frm:frm},
            })
            .done(function(response){
             console.log(response.message)
            });
        });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="fixed-bottom">
    <form id="message-form"  user_id="{{u.id}}" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" id="user_id" name="user_id" value="{{u.id}}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div id="text" class="col-10">
                    {{ msgform.text }}
                </div>

                <div class="col-1">
                    <button id="submit" class="btn"  type="submit"><img height="30px" src="/static/img/send-button.png" alt="send"></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><br>
    </form>  
</div>
```

Thanx in advanced

Comment: What is `frm:frm` supposed to do? You're trying to submit a complete form (wrapped in a jQuery object)...

Comment: Possible dupe: [$(this).serialize() — How to add a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6539502/this-serialize-how-to-add-a-value)

Comment: Sorry if  it is very basic. I am very new to `javascript`. I make variable so that I can access  from in backend.. is I make any mistake. .

Comment: @Andreas when I try `frm:frm.serialize()` instead of `frm:frm`           I get  this error 
     `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem in sending data.

When I use `JSON.stringify` to post data
and accept in views as `json.loads(request.POST.get('frm'))` everything works fine

```js
$('#messageform').on('submit', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var frm = {
    'user_id': $('#user_id').attr('value'),
    'text': $('#form_message').val()
  };
  frm = JSON.stringify(frm);
  
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "message/message_form/",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
      csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
      'frm': frm
    },
  })
});
```

views.py

```
def post(self, request):
        dictionary = json.loads(request.POST.get('frm'))
        print('=================',dictionary)
        u = get_object_or_404(User,pk=dictionary['user_id'])
        msg = message.objects.filter(sender=request.user).filter(receiver=u).all() | message.objects.filter(sender=u).filter(receiver=request.user).all()
        u = message.objects.create(sender=request.user,receiver=u,text=dictionary['text'])
        #if request.user != u and u.objects.filter(receiver__sender=request.user,receiver__receiver=u,receiver__read=False).exists :
        #    notify.send(request.user, recipient=u, verb="message you please read in message box",public=False)
        # msg = message.objects.filter(sender=request.user).filter(receiver=u).all() | message.objects.filter(sender=u).filter(receiver=request.user).all() 
        msg = dictionary['text']
        data = { "message":msg}
        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Your answer fixes the problem simply because you added the `val()` method call to the `#form_message` jQuery object. You don't need to manually `JSON.stringify()` anything.